# change values in a column according to their associated labels

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to change the value of the data in the last column according to their associated value in the 1st column. For instance, if `state` is "AK" then the `comm_rank` should be "1", if the `state` is "AL" then the `comm_rank` should be "2", if the `state` is "AR" then the `comm_rank` should be "3", etc..

Anyone could suggest me a efficient way to loop through the last column and then change their value accordingly? My original data frame is much larger than this sample, so I need to do this efficiently.

Sample data frame:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If the ranks are based on the alphabetic order of `state`, how about `as.numeric(factor(dat$state))`?

Comment: You could also try, guess what, `rank`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**reproducible data**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(state = sample(c("AK", "AL", "AR"), 10, replace=TRUE),
```

**`dplyr` solution**

```
v <- 1:3
names(v) <- c("AK", "AL", "AR")
v
# AK AL AR 
# 1  2  3

library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(comm_rank = v[state])
```

**base R solution**

```
df$comm_rank <- v[df$state]
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(INPUT, comm_rank = case_when(state == "AK" ~ 1,
                                    state == "AL" ~ 2,
                                    state == "AR" ~ 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

using base R you can do:

```
  df[ncol(df)] <- as.numeric(as.factor(df[,"state"]))
```